# CakePHP updateAll() not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using updateAll() instead of what a tutorial suggested

`$this->Post->id = $id;`

I have no id column in my table. When I run this code -

```
    public function edit($user_id = null) {
    if (!$user_id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $user_info = array('conditions' => array('User.user_ID' => $user_id));
    $user = $this->User->find('all', $user_info);
    if (!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User ID'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('put')) {
        $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
        //$this->set('new_user', $data);
        $this->User->updateAll(
        array( 'User.status' => 'ooactive' ), //fields to update
        array( 'User.user_id' => $user_id ));
    }
}
```

I get this error -

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ooactive' in 'field list'
>   SQL Query: UPDATE `Smooch`.`users` AS `User` SET `User`.`status` = ooactive WHERE `User`.`user_id` = 3

I do not know why I am getting this error any help would be awesome, thanks

**EDIT:**

Current code, I decided it to do it the way shown from the blog tutorial at CakePHP.org -

```
    public function edit($user_id = null) {
    if (!$user_id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $user_info = array('conditions' => array('User.user_ID' => $user_id));
    $user = $this->User->find('all', $user_info);
    if (!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User ID'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('put')) {
         $this->User->user_id = "user_id";
         $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
         if($this->User->save($data));
    }}
```

ERROR -

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   SQL Query: INSERT INTO `Smooch`.`users` (`status`) VALUES ('inaaaaaaactive')

This turns it into a INSERT statement, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's OK. The documentation says: (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions)

> The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually using DboSource::value(). For example if one of your model methods was calling updateAll() you would do the following:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value($value, 'string');
$this->updateAll(
    array('Baker.approved' => true),
    array('Baker.created <=' => $value)
);
```

So, use `$db->value('ooactive', 'string')` to escape the status.

Comment: I tried the above and it led to more issues so I tried going back to the way the official cakePHP tutorials says to do it -  $this->Post->id = $id; This is where I think the magic happens that makes it an update statement. How would I set up this code($this->Post->id = $id;) if my primary key is user_id? I will update my post to reflect current code.

Comment: You can set the primary key to other field with $this->Post->primaryKey = 'field'; I don't know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, updateAll() cannot just be used like save() in 2.x.
You need to manually quote your input, as such it logically (and the error message states that you need to use):

`$this->User->updateAll(
    array( 'User.status' => '"ooactive"'),
    array( 'User.user_id' => $user_id )
);`

Answer (score 0):

$this->Bookcopy->updateAll(['Bookcopy.status' => 'AVAILABLE'],['Bookcopy.status'=>'REQUESTED'])

**Error:** SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AVAILABLE' in 'field list'

**SQL Query:** UPDATE `practice_bookchum`.`bookcopies` AS `Bookcopy` LEFT JOIN `practice_bookchum`.`books_stores` AS `Book_Store` ON (`Bookcopy`.`book_store_id` = `Book_Store`.`id`) SET `Bookcopy`.`status` = AVAILABLE WHERE `Bookcopy`.`status` = 'REQUESTED'

Model::updateAll(array $fields, mixed $conditions)

error occurs when I pass $fields as associate array with value

> I did it....

```
$db = $this->Bookcopy->getDataSource();
$value = 'AVAILABLE';
$value = $db->value($value, 'String');

$this->Bookcopy->updateAll(['status' => $value],['Bookcopy.status'=>'REQUESTED'])

{data: "Borrow", status: "success"}
data:"Borrow"
status:"success"
```